# Deserialize json string and extract to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net-core, json.net

My API response is a json string and I need to convert it to a model somehow using deserialize and IEnumerable.

Here is my code and in debug I can see my returned json string:

```
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

However, if I try and use the below code to deserialize it to its model I receive a build error...

```
productKeys = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                     <IEnumerable<ProductKey>>(responseString);
```

The error is:

> "cannot convert 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

How can I get around this?

**Update from comments**

here is my `responseString`...

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "resultMessage": "Success",
    "keyInfo": {
        "trialKey": "46C8F3CBF2D09077D29325E55FAFCBFCBFF923CE2A2F3C189D49E4BC7FD9AA9A",
        "goodTill": "2020-07-19",
        "applyInstructions": "Use command GBLAPPKEY PRODUCT(MFT)to apply your trial key."
    }
}
```

This is my ProductKey model...

```
public class ProductKey     
{          
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string resultMessage { get; set; }     
    public List<keyInfo> data { get; set; }      
}      

public class keyInfo     
{      
    public string trialKey { get; set; }    
    public string goodTill { get; set; }    
    public string applyInstructions { get; set; }      
}
```

And here is the error... I believe it is saying my model needs accommodate an array, but why? I"m not using an array in the JSON...?

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
> (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[coreiWS.Models.ProductKey]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly

Comment: Are you sure you are getting build error on this line of code? Can you share a sample of json you are trying to deserialize?

Answer (score 1):

[`DeserializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=netcore-3.1) is a method in System.Text.Json which actually takes a stream, not a string as a parameter.

You already have a string, so you should be able to deserialize the string using `DeserializeObject` instead:

If you're using Newtonsoft.Json the following will deserialize:

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json
var productKeys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ProductKey>>(responseString);
```

---

**Update** from your comments:

For the JSON string result you posted in the comment, your `ProductKey` class should look like this:

```
public class ProductKey 
{
    public int success { get; set; } 
    public string resultMessage { get; set; } 
    public KeyInfo keyInfo { get; set; } 
}

public class KeyInfo
{
    public string trialKey { get; set; } 
    public string goodTill { get; set; } 
    public string applyInstructions { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like the problem is with the definition of `keyInfo` in the `ProductKey` class.

If the JSON only contains a single `ProductKey`, you can omit the `IEnumerable`:

```
var productKeys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductKey>(responseString);
```

Comment: Haldo. Thank you. Sorry for the messy replies. I generally don’t use SO so learning. Ok well I’ve made great progress. The IENumerable appears to be needed for a list of Json data (arrays). Mine contains a single entity so refactoring code to remove IENumerable got me to where I need to be. I really appreciate your guidance. Thx